# Dropping the disco ball to achieve accidental kill

Tags: hitman-absolution

While playing level 5th "Hunter and Hunted" (Vixen club area) at expert difficulty, I have attempted almost over 10 times to get the timing right in order to drop the disco ball over the target "Dom Osmond" in order to achieve accidental kill rating but almost every time I have managed to drop the ball drops over his head while also causing civilian causalities.

[image]

However, whenever I go look at the place where it was dropped, I don't see any other body aside from the target's own. I am not sure if this is some bug in Windows version of the game but every time the same thing happens with no success (i.e. no clean accidental kill).

I looked around on the internet and didn't find any helpful clues except these which don't seem to work.

Press the button:

- when the target says the words "come in" or "under" while he's shouting at crowd.
- or, just after he pushes the disco girl away from stage.
- or, when the disco ball is about to align towards his position.

Any ideas from the people who have actually done this or tried over and over in order to get past it at same or higher difficulty levels maybe?

Comment: Very Good question!

Comment: So, I finally did it however I think that was luck :D. I just waited a little more until he was about to leave the stage. I'd still like to know if there's a sure way to perform it or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tested and did it the fourth time now. The trick is to wait until his voice goes inaudible or when you cannot hear it anymore. At this point I think the people standing around him become aware of the faulty disco balls as he warns them to move away from the stage. Then, just hit the button at the right time. At least this works for expert difficulty level and I am not sure about the other difficulty levels.